# Get the first field when count reaches a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to segment clients by the first date that their count of orders reached a specific value.

for example, we have a table of orders

```
ID, ClientID, Date

1,  1, 1/1/2011
2,  1  2/1/2011
3,  1  3/1/2011
4,  1  4/1/2011
```

I would like to get all the clients who has at least 3 orders and get the Date field when they reached 3 orders.
on my example, the query will show:

```
ClientID: 1, Date: 3/1/2011
```

(cause on the 3/1/2011, the client reached 3 orders)

How can I do it?

Thanks

Update:

I'm looking at your solutions (thank you very much!) but I need to do the same thing also with SUM (lets say the table above has a field called amount and I would like to segment the clients and get the first date that the client orders reached to $100)
I though that the solutions will help me understand the logic and easily convert the count to sum and make a new query but I got little bit lost here.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would select all the clients with 3 orders with the date of 3rd order.

```
--DECLARE @clientID INT
--SET @clientID = 1
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 3      -- Set the count to this variable.

SELECT  ClientID, [Date]
FROM    [yourtable] a
WHERE   COALESCE(    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                      FROM [yourtable] b 
                      WHERE b.[Date] < a.[Date] and b.ClientID = a.ClientID ),0) = @count - 1
ORDER BY ClientID
```

To select single client with date of 3rd order where could be modified with additional condition for that.

```
AND a.ClientID = @clientID
```

**UPDATE** based on question update - This query with little modification from count woud give you the running sum selection. There are few more techniques listed here for [running sum](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/calculating-running-totals).

```
DECLARE @sum INT
SET @count = 100      -- Set the amount to this variable.

SELECT  ClientID, [Date]
FROM    [yourtable] a
WHERE   ( a.Amount + COALESCE(    (SELECT SUM(b.Amount) 
                      FROM [yourtable] b 
                      WHERE b.[Date] < a.[Date] and b.ClientID = a.ClientID ),0) ) = @sum
ORDER BY ClientID
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've done. despite the fact that this solution might or might not be the best approach to get the count like I first stated, this is the best solution for both of my problems

Answer (score 1):

I would do something along the lines of this:

```
DECLARE @ClientId int, @RowNumber int
SELECT @ClientId = 1, @RowNumber = 3

SELECT ClientId, [Date]
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP (@RowNumber) ClientId, [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
    FROM Test
    WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
) D
WHERE RowNumber = @RowNumber
```

You can put the client id and number of rows to process as parameters to whatever procedure you end up using.

Comment: Is it possible to use this query but on a sum of a field and not on count?

Comment: Sounds like the goalposts have moved a little here :)

Comment: The problem with what you're now asking is that you're looking for a running total, and as far as I'm aware you can't do that easily in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT clientid, date
FROM (
     SELECT id, 
            clientid, 
            row_number() over (partition by clientid order by date) as running_count,
            date
     FROM orders
) t
WHERE running_count = 3
```

**Edit**
My solution cannot be extended to cover the sum() requirement due to the incomplete support for windowing functions in SQL Server.

But for completeness, I include an example for that nevertheless:

```
SELECT clientid, date
FROM (
     SELECT id, 
            clientid, 
            row_number() over (partition by clientid order by date) as running_count,
            sum(amount) over (partition by clientid order by date) as running_sum,
            date
     FROM orders
) t
WHERE running_sum = 100
   OR running_count = 3
```

But again: this will **not** work in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Test table and test data

```
declare @T table (ID int, ClientID int, [Date] datetime, Amount money)

insert into @T values
(1,  1,  '1/1/2011', 10),
(2,  1,  '2/1/2011', 20),
(3,  1,  '3/1/2011', 30),
(4,  1,  '4/1/2011', 40),
(5,  2,  '1/1/2011', 10),
(6,  2,  '2/1/2011', 20),
(7,  2,  '3/1/2011', 30)
```

Getting the third row is not so hard. This is the same as solution as a_horse_with_no_name provided.

```
declare @Row int = 3

;with cte as 
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by ClientID order by [Date]) as rn
  from @T
)  
select *
from cte
where rn = @Row
```

To get the row when running sum exceeds a value is a bit harder. Here is a loop version using a temporary table to update the running sum.

```
declare @sum money = 30

select *, cast(0 as money) as Running
into #T
from @T

declare @rn int = 1

;with cte as
(
  select
    Running,
    Amount,
    row_number() over(partition by ClientID order by [Date]) as rn
  from #T
)  
update cte set
  Running = Amount
where
  rn = @rn

while @@rowcount >= 1
begin
  set @rn = @rn + 1

  ;with cte as
  (
    select
      Running,
      Amount,
      row_number() over(partition by ClientID order by [Date]) as rn
    from #T
  )  
  update cte set
    Running = Running + Amount
  where rn = @rn
end

;with cte as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by ClientID order by [Date]) as rn
  from #T
  where Running >= @sum
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1

drop table #T
```